# The resistance value for PWM circuit uses STM32F103C8T6 and MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, stm32, pwm, resistance

I want to design a PWM circuit using STM32f103C8T6 and MOSFET as shown below.
I use MOSFET IRF3708 because Gate-to-Source Voltage low. but low power.
MOSFET IRF3205 has a large power but Gate-to-Source Voltage high. So I have R3 resistors to 12V.

I want to ask the resistance value R1, R2, R3?
If the value is high, the pulse is distorted by the discharge of the charge.
I am worried that the low value will be high. So STM32 or Mosfet will be damaged.

[image]

Comment: What's the PWM frequency? What's the minimum "ON" time in your application? What voltage and current are you aim to switch, or at least what load are you going to switch with PWM? There are MOSFETs with higher voltage & current switching capability with low gate-source voltages. Have you checked them (*logic-level gate MOSFETs*)?

Comment: The maximum frequency is 20kHz. The shortest time is 1%. Downloads are electromagnetic valves open and close in percentage. The current I want is 20A. I have not found a high current and low VGS voltage.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy want to use that circuit then R1 and R2 zero. For R3 choose reasonably low (330R ?). But be ware that due low value R3 your circuit will have high quiescent current and even with that opening time for Q8 will be unnecessarily long and that will chreate excessive switching losses (search for some tutorial about "MOSFET switching losses"). You should find one of many ICs MOSFET drivers which makes exactly what do you need and much better... they are cheap.